# How do I get a rewritten URL in JSP?

Tags: jsp, url-rewriting

I have a JSP page at an address like this:

> http://example.com/foo/bar/rawr/something.jsp

When I output `request.getRequestURL()`, I get something totally different:

> http://111.111.111.111/rawr/something.jsp

Note the domain changed to an IP and `/foo/bar` is missing. How do I get the true URL that the browser requested using JSP?

Comment: Are you using a proxy in front of your Java EE server? If so, that particular proxy could (should) have set some specific request header.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure since it is not my server. I'll inspect the headers to see if there is anything useful there.

Comment: @BalusC It turns out you are right. There is a proxy and its giving me a header for the rewritten url. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Glad I could help you. I reposted it as an answer (I initially posted it as a comment because it wasn't explicitly clear if you were using a proxy or not, but at least, the symptoms are recognizeable enough :) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if there is a proxy (such as Apache HTTPD) in front of the Java EE server. The particular proxy could (should) have set the original request URL as a request header. At least, all self-respected proxies do that.

You can crawl through all request headers as follows to find it out:

```
for (String name : Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames())) {
    System.out.println(name + "=" + Collections.list(request.getHeaders(name)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get a rewritten URL excluding domain:

```
String rewrittenURL = request.getHeader("REDIRECT_URL");
```